# portable way to store milliseconds with chrono

Tags: c++, date, c++11, c++14, c++-chrono

I've a code as follows -

```
int main(){
    ....

    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1);

    ....
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `time` here gives output as `l` with `typeid().name()` method, but is it safe to assume that if I replace auto with `long` type, the variable will still store the correct amount of milliseconds across different machines?

I need it because I cannot specify `auto` as type in class members, since they aren't constexpr or static where it might've been possible. And my intent is to send the data to browser where I can do `var d = new Date(time)` and it displays correct time. The communication part has been figured out via json format, I'm only stuck at how to store it correctly across different systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the existing answers are good.  But as long as you're in C++ I encourage you to make the data member of type:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>
```

I know this is an ugly mouthful, but it can easily be made prettier.  It is also easy to use.  And it will help prevent run time errors in your C++ code.

**Make it prettier**

I recommend this templated using:

```
template <class Duration>
    using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;
```

Now you can make your data member have type:

```
sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> time_;
```

This is much more readable, and it *exactly* preserves the semantics that you are storing a time point, not an arbitrary number, or the number of calories in grapefruit.

**Type Safety**

Let's say six months from now you are re-visiting this code and you write:

```
auto z = x.time_ + y.time_;
```

If you had previously decided to give `time_` type `std::int64_t`, or `std::chrono::milliseconds::rep`, then the above new line of code compiles *and creates a run time error.*  It makes no sense to add two points in time.  Tomorrow + today is nonsensical.

However if you had previously decided to give `time_` type `sys_time<milliseconds>` as I suggest, the above line of code creating `z` **does not compile.**  The type system has detected the logic error *at compile time*.  Now you are forced to immediately re-visit your logic and discover why you are attempting to add two time points.  Maybe it was just a type-o and you meant to subtract them (which is logical, compiles, and results in a `duration` of type `milliseconds`).

**Ease of use**

You can assign `now()` to your `time_` data member with this simple syntax:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
time_ = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Now `time_` is just another `system_clock`-based `time_point` but with a precision of `milliseconds`.  For outputting to json you can get the internal signed integral value with:

```
json_stream << time_.time_since_epoch().count();
```

For parsing in from json you can:

```
std::int64_t temp;
json_stream >> temp;
time_ = sys_time<milliseconds>{milliseconds{temp}};
```

Comment: Yes sure, and I'm a big fan of yours btw :D was going to use your date library anyways.

Comment: @hg_git:  Awesome, thanks.  `date::sys_time<D>` comes pre-made in date.h.

Comment: Why not type the variable as
decltype(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) start;

Comment: The OP expressed a desire to store at milliseconds precision.  Your suggestion will result in some other precision.

Answer (score 6):

> [...] is it safe to assume that if I replace auto with `long` type, the variable will still store the correct amount of milliseconds across different machines?

No, you need *a signed integer type of at least 45 bits*, which `long` is not guarantee to be. You should use `std::chrono::milliseconds::rep`:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
milliseconds::rep time = 
    duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Also note that in term of portability, the `system_clock`'s epoch is not guaranteed to be January 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC by the standard (even if it is the case most of the time).

Comment: waaiiit what? `the system_clock's epoch is not guaranteed to be January 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC by the standard`, well then how do I check for that? I mean is it dependent on compilers and their versions, or operating systems, or architecture of machine?

Comment: @hg_git You can obtain a `std::tm` from `system_clock` using `to_time_t` and `gmtime` and check whether this is the right date, and if it is not, you'd need to do some extra computation. The epoch depends on the system, not on the compiler, see [wikipedia[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing). It is unlikely that the epoch differs from the UNIX epoch, but on a standard point-of-view, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: At this time, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC is the de facto standard (but unspecified by the C++ standard).  I plan to try to make it specified with a near future proposal.  Also see information about this narrowly averted catastrophe:  https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/780816381394550784

Comment: What is the minimum underlying size of milliseconds::rep? Are all platforms guaranteed to have uint64_t?

Comment: @RobinDavies As said in the answer, the standard guarantees that `milliseconds::rep` is at least 45 bits (to cover +/- 292 years). Each standard durations up to hours covers at least +/- 292 years.

Comment: @hg_git: Windows system epoch: January 1, 1601; Macintosh systems use January 1, 1904, and Digital Equipment Corporation's Virtual Memory System (VMS) uses November 17, 1858. I'm not sure which of these epochs is surfaced in c++. But I don't actually need to know, do I? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will work and is portable, but i suggest to use a more straightforward approach for counting milliseconds:

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()
```

This will definitely work because .count() returns a std::chrono::milliseconds::rep which is "A signed integral type of at least 45 bits" and should fit in long.

Note: it is not guaranteed that system_clock will have millisecond resolution. But in any case you will get result in milliseconds.

Side note: I can be good to utilize `using namespace std::chrono;` because this will reduce code length significantly.